Interference in the baked normal map
My first experience in baking normals map, so what went wrong, I can't say. The only difference between the high-poly and low-poly models is the recess in the middle (which, for some reason, was baked perfectly)

Hello, hard to understand, could you please share your file?

Instructions for sharing your blendfile.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Assuming you are using overlapping geometry, there might be issues with faces intersecting between the mesh you cast the normal map from and the mesh you are baking onto. It's hard to tell without seeing both meshes. It might be (my assumption) that you need to use cage baking, or something else is off about the vertex data of your low poly mesh. If the normal map is having regular errors it might be something other than "mesh sticking out". You can try to see if baking to a different mesh looks like this as well. Please provide additional screenshots, too.
